# What is this plant with red stalks and greenish-red leaves?

Tags: plants, plant-identification, pennsylvania

This plant has been sprouting up from time to time in my yard. I've been cutting them down as I see them, but it has me curious.

[image: plant]

What is this plant?  Currently its maybe 10 inches tall, which red stems/stalks and the leaves are green with the "newer" leaves having a slight red hue to them.

Comment: Is it a tree growing from seed?

Comment: I think it might be St John's wort, would need to see flowers to be sure though. FWIW I have something similar in my garden an it's one hell of a weed.

Comment: @bob1 I'll be sure to post new pictures if it ever looks any different

Comment: @TimmyJim try crushing the leaves - if it smells unpleasant, St J's wort is a very strong possibility.

Comment: @bob1 I crushed a leaf and I'd say it didn't smell anything abnormal. Just kind of like a grass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lots of digging, I believe this is a [*Lagerstroemia indica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagerstroemia_indica), better known as a  **Crape Myrtle** or Crepe Myrtle.  This is the "juvenile" stage of this flowering tree it seems. [Wikipedia has an image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Crepe_myrtle-juvenile_leaves.jpg) of a similar looking plant, though not exactly the same.  This lead me down the path of finding out it was a Crape Myrtle.

[image: plant found on wikipedia]

I'm fairly confident that this is it because where I keep finding these plants is around my large pink-flower baring tree that I now know is a Crape Myrtle! I originally thought these were some sort of weed and not the start of a new tree.